# Fault recovery of a UAV using MATLAB

Tags: control, transfer-function, matlab, fault

I'm currently investigating fault recovery in a UAV using MATLAB.

*I've been given several variables:*

- **phi** = the roll angle
- **psi** = the yaw/heading angle
- **beta** = the side slip
- **p** = roll rate
- **r** = yaw/heading rate
- **delta_r** = angle of the rudder
- **delta_a** = angle of the aileron (the aileron is currently inactive).

**My input is the rudder angle.**

**I've simulated a step fault in the yaw/heading sensor and I'm trying to recover from it.**

*To detect that there was a fault in the heading sensors:* I compared the actual side-slip with the modeled side slip. If there is a difference between the "real' system and the model in heading angle, but no difference in side-slip, then the heading sensor is faulty.

*To recover from this fault:* I want to reconfigure the side-slip so I can use it to determine the heading/yaw angle. In order to do this I need to multiply the side-slip by the transfer function between side-slip and heading/yaw angle.

**We've been given the following equations:**

[image]

**I'm having some trouble coming up with a transfer function between side slip and heading angle.**

*I figured the best thing to do, as I am using a simulation filled with arrays, is to turn all the derivatives into their discrete equivalent* - of course this is means I'm not using a transfer function, but an equation. Taking the equation for the derivative of beta and discretizing it...

[image]

**When I plug this in, the system doesn't recover.**

**I even tried doing Laplace transforms**, *but I get stuck here:*

[image]

**And I'm not sure how I could apply that in MATLAB**

*Is there a mistake in my logic or approach?* *How would I turn the discrete system into a transfer function?*

Comment: Is this an EE problem?

Comment: **1)** Wouldn't a transfer function be between an input and an output ? Is \$\beta\$ an input to this system ? (You say that rudder is an input but nothing about side slip). **2)** If there is a cross wind in reality but not in your model, the side slip will be different between reality and model. What will you do then ? **3)** Side slip is a function of velocity, but heading is an angle. How can you reconstruct heading from side slip ?

Comment: **4)** "*I need to multiply the side-slip by the transfer function between side-slip and heading/yaw angle.*" Where is this idea from ? This is not a good method if the transfer function between side-slip and heading is not a stable transfer function. (I think it will not be a stable transfer function; but I am not sure)

Comment: @Andyaka OP seems to be trying to do state estimation (or fault detection). I think it would be in the realm of EE.

Comment: 1) you are correct, side slip is not an input into the system, but an output 2) I'll consider that at a later stage, if I can't get the perfect model working I have even less chance of getting the real system to work unfortunately, however I appreciate your insight on this.

Comment: 3&4) You are right, I did make an error in saying that i need to find the TF between side slip and heading. I am trying to do "output reconstitution" - I have a side slip sensor and a heading sensor. To be able to use the side slip output i have to divide the TF of the side slip by the TF of the heading angle, but again, the equations all rely on each other, and I only have these equations to go by. An "easy" solution, seeing as i'm assuming a perfect model, is just to replace the faulty sensor output with the modeled output, but I wouldn't learn from that, which I would really like to do :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [State Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer) ? It is a method of reconstructing states (\$\psi\$ in your case) from inputs and measured outputs (\$\delta_r\$ and \$\beta\$). You can also try reading upon Kalman filters.